# How to get a count of the times the first occurrence of an unique ID is on a specific day?

Tags: sql, count, dml

So I have two tables:

customer_dimension:

```
sk_customer | first_name | last_name | acq_channel | acq_date |  customer_id
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
411           Alex          Hum       Offline        2019-03-02  44586344
422           Eric          Spong     Offline        2019-02-02  44323233
447           Eddie         Peng      TV             2019-05-07  44782233
```

boxes_shipped:

```
box_id | fk_box_sku | fk_customer | fk_geography | week |  delivery_date
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
123      321          447           Syd            2       2019-04-02      
124      322          422           WA             3       2019-02-05
125      323          411           WA             4       2019-05-07
```

fk_customer references sk_customer through a foreign key restraint.

I would like to find a way to count the number of times the FIRST occurrence of fk_customer has on a tuesday, i.e. a count of the number of people who receive their first box on a tuesday. So if a customer ordered a 2nd box on a tuesday, it would not increase the count.

How would I write a query to see if the delivery date is tuesday? And then count the first occurrence of fk_customer only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing your requirements,

- For counting fk_customer orders in every single date you can use `group by delivery_date, fk_customer` and use  `count(*)` aggregator on that.
- For getting a particular day name from date, you can search for library function for the DBMS specific to yours.

A MySQL implementation of your required query would be:

```
select count(*) repeatedOrders, fk_customer, delivery_date from boxes_shipped group by delivery_date, fk_customer where dayname(delivery_date) = 'Tuesday'.
```

Comment: I've tried something similar:
`select count(*) as 'Tuesday First Delivery'
from boxes_shipped
where DATE_FORMAT(delivery_date,'%a') = 'Wed'
group by delivery_date;` 

Is there a way that I can get the query to count only the first occurrence of fk_customer based on date?

Comment: yes for that you need to use rank() to rank individual orders for a particular date and then you can filter by rank=1.

Comment: you can try something like this,
`select rank() over(partition by delivery_date, fk_customer)  as 'Tuesday First Delivery' from boxes_shipped where DATE_FORMAT(delivery_date,'%a') = 'Tue'`

not tested though, check it once and then you can filter by that **rank being 1**

Check [this](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-rank-function/) for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select fk_customer, min(delivery_date) as first_delivery_date
      from boxes_shipped
      group by fk_customer
     ) c
where dayname(first_delivery_date) = 'Tuesday';
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is wondering, I used:

```
with order_values as(
     select *, rank() over(partition by delivery_date,fk_customer)
as order_value_rank
from boxes_shipped
where DATE_FORMAT(delivery_date, '%a') = 'Tues'
)

select count(*) as 'Number of people that received their 1st box on Tues'
from order_values
where order_value_rank =1;
```

Comment: If you found my answer influencing please mark it as answer also, thanks.